Azure App Service - Authenticating to Log Analytics
I've created a app in Azure App Service which uses Entra ID auth (Easy auth). Part of this app accesses a log analytics workspaces and run queries.
I want the application to run queries on behalf of the user.
I've already setup delgated permissions under 'API Permissions' in the app
The application currently uses a managed identity and authenticates via api.loganalytics.io.
I'm not sure how I can get the user who logged into the Azure App Service application bearer token to log analytics (If that makes sense).
Could someone help me out?

To do this you need to use an on behalf off token.
The app uses the token from the user to create a new token, that has information (including the id of the user) from the original token.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow
